# finding the Enterprise Library binaries path

Tags: c#-4.0

After installing the Enterprise Library config console.., When I want to use the Enterprise lirary to open the configuration file..,

I want to give the path for the Enterprise Library binaries path property, I can't find the location of the binaries where I have installed in my pc..

So, how can I find the binaries path for the Enterprise Library 5.0..?
it is giving me the error..

"Error Launching the configuration console.. Could not locate the Enterprise Library binaries"

Comment: Install http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15104 , build solution, Copy dll's and unistall

Comment: Thanks... is it possible that we can make it after coping dlls and uninstalling it..?

Comment: Maybe a possibility is copy dll's to a  root's folder solution, like /dlls or something. Then change reference path to this folder... to improve portability